# Trying to make a Discord bot, but module cannot be found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord.js

[Image depicts my index.js properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQIXP.png) I've been trying to recode a Discord bot I previously lost a while back. I followed [THIS](https://thomlom.dev/create-a-discord-bot-under-15-minutes/) tutorial to the dot, which I've done before to make a different bot. It worked like a charm. I'm at the point where it says to run the command `npm run dev` to start the bot.
Expected outcome: The discord bot starts up successfully
Actual result:

```
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\beans> npm run dev

┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                  npm update check failed                  │
│            Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\User\.config │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

> beans@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\User\Desktop\beans
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js index.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\beans\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

So then, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "beans",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

here's my index.js, minus the bot token:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})
client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.content === "ping") {
    msg.reply("Pong!")
  }
})
client.login("mytoken")
```

I've attempted running `npm clear cache,` which did nothing. I've tried recreating the file entirely, also doing nothing. I'm on Windows 10 if that helps. This is my first question so I apologize if I haven't provided enough information, but I hope this comes across clearly.

EDIT: I've noticed that, compared to the last time I started a different bot, the terminal/powershell states `starting node index.js index.js` instead of `starting node index.js` like last time. I think I might see the error though I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it can't find index.js maybe it has the wrong name or it is in the wrong directory.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with this post, can you post a pic of the working directory?

Comment: Eep... I'm entirely new to this but I added the image. I hope that's what you meant, I'm sorry if that wasn't.

Comment: I think they wanted you to do directory listing of the working directory

use  the command dir

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with the following results below.  The token problem was expected, but it did find the module

```
C:\git\beans
> npm run dev

> beans@1.0.0 dev C:\git\beans
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 2.0.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
(node:47012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be your NODE_PATH environment variable is messed up.

try the following to see if you have anything set there.
c:\git\beans

> set NODE_PATH

Answer (score 0):

False alarm... my index.js decided to save as index.js.txt despite only displaying index.js. I switched notepad programs and it worked like a charm.

Comment: glad you got it working. If you aren't already, you may wish to try visual studio code for your js.   https://code.visualstudio.com/

Also I recommend turning on this feature:  File Explorer > View > File Name Extensions so that the extension always shows in Windows.